# postgresql matching with substring

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Using python pstcopg2

I want to make a data frame like

```
df = sql.read_sql("""SELECT objects.sampleid, MAX(objects.projid) AS projid, 
                            MAX(samples.t01) AS hdrfilename, MAX(samples.t06) AS ctdfilename, 
                            MAX(objects.objdate) || ' ' || MAX(objects.objtime) AS objdatetime, 
                            MAX(objects.latitude) AS latitude, MAX(objects.longitude) AS longitude, 
                            MAX(objects.orig_id) AS orig_id 
        FROM samples, objects 
        WHERE objects.projid in (%s) and objects.orig_id LIKE '%samples.orig_id%'
        GROUP BY objects.sampleid"""%(projid_list), mydb)
```

But an error message occurred

```
    GROUP BY objects.sampleid"""%(projid_list), mydb) 
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I guess the main problem came from this line,

```
objects.orig_id LIKE '%samples.orig_id%'
```

If I apply the code with

```
objects.orig_id = samples.orig_id
```

It works, but that's not exactly what I want.
I want if the objects.orig_id contains samples.orig_id, I get the data.

How to correct the above code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the `%` by `%%`.

Something like this should work:

```
LIKE '%%samples.orig_id%%'
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/functions-matching.html But if you see the Note in the website, they just use '%'. What's the difference between them?

Comment: The doc that you are referring is a postgres doc. What that basically means is, in postgres, you can search a pattern using `%` sign. But when you are using it through `python` , you need to escape `%` as it is a special keyword in python.

Comment: Yes. Just one more thing, Can I just use '_' instead of '%'?